# XHR Requests not returning all data from website

Tags: python, json

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows 8 64 bit. I have some code that iterates through a series of date variables to create XHR submissions to a website. These attempt to pull down football data for matches played on the days iterated through. If no matches were played that today a message is printed to this effect.

The code I have works fine, except for it is not returning any data for anything but the most recent season. The page I am trying to scrape is here:

http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/26

The calendar allows you to toggle between dates and XHR requests populate this data on the page. The code I am using to do this is:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td
from ast import literal_eval
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import time
import re

list1 = [2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013]
list2 = [2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014]


for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    print "list1 - " + str(x)
    print "list2 - " + str(y)


    d1 = date(x,11,01)
    d2 = date(y,5,31)

    delta = d2 - d1



    for i in range(delta.days + 1):

        time1 =  str(d1 + td(days=i))
        time2 = time1.split("-", 1)[0]
        time3 = time1.split("-", -1)[1]
        time4 = time1.rsplit("-", 1)[-1]

        time2 = int(time2)
        time3 = int(time3)
        time4 = int(time4)

        date1 = datetime(year=time2, month=time3, day=time4)

        url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/8273/Fixtures/'

        params = {'d': date1.strftime('%Y%m%d'), 'isAggregate': 'false'}
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}

        response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)


        try:
            fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)


            if fixtures is not None and len(fixtures) > 0: # If there are fixtures
                print ",\n".join([", ".join(str(x) for x in fixture) for fixture in fixtures]) # `fixtures` is a nested list
                time.sleep(0.5)    


            else:

               print "No Fixtures Today: " + date1.isoformat()
               time.sleep(0.5) 

        except SyntaxError:

            print "Error!!!"
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

As far as I understand it, all the data for all available seasons should all be accessed via the same method and from the same place. Can anyone see why this is not working?

Thanks

Comment: features is always `not None `

Comment: @PadraicCunningham even for an empty response? what should this be changed to? also, how come this works for the most recent season, but not previous ones? thanks.

Comment: I have not looked over your code yet but is comparison is not what you use to check for empty lists

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ive tried the following, but it keeps throwing up a syntax error at the first opening curly bracket: 'for (member in fixtures) {
                if (data[member] != null)
                print ",\n".join([", ".join(str(x) for x in fixture) for fixture in fixtures]) # `fixtures` is a nested list
                time.sleep(0.5)
            }

            for (member in fixtures) {
                if (data[member] == null)
                print "No Fixtures Today: " + date1.isoformat()
                time.sleep(0.5) 
            }'

Comment: I answered you the other day, all you need is `if fixtures` on the literal_eval, why are you changing the lists to strings?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham someone answered on another thread that it wasnt a good idea converting a a response to a string and stripping out characters i didnt want using regex and proposed this instead.

Comment: enter `http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/6531/Fixtures/?d=20120901&isAggregate=false` in your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each season is with different tournament ID wich means that the URL is different. I changed the code to work with all years and their tournament IDs

```
import json
import requests
import time

from datetime import date, timedelta

year_tournament_map = {
    2013: 8273,
    2012: 6978,
    2011: 5861,
    2010: 4940,
    2009: 3419,
    2008: 2689,
    2007: 2175,
    2006: 1645,
    2005: 1291,
    2004: 903,
    2003: 579,
    2002: 421,
    2001: 243,
    2000: 114,
    1999: 26,
}

years = sorted(year_tournament_map.keys())
url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/%s/Fixtures/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}

for year in years:
    start_date = date(year, 11, 1)
    end_date = date(year + 1, 5, 31)
    delta = end_date - start_date

    for days  in range(delta.days + 1):
        time.sleep(0.5) 

        test_date = start_date + timedelta(days=days)

        params = {'d': str(test_date).replace('-', ''), 'isAggregate': 'false'}
        response = requests.get(url % year_tournament_map[year], params=params, headers=headers)

        try:
            json_data = response.content.replace("'", '"').replace(',,', ',null,')
            fixtures = json.loads(json_data)

        except ValueError:
            print "Error!!!"

        else:

            if fixtures:  # If there are fixtures
                print ",\n".join([", ".join(str(x) for x in fixture) for fixture in fixtures])  # `fixtures` is a nested list

            else:
               print "No Fixtures Today: %s" %  test_date
```

Comment: As I understand the author of the question want to get the data for "FA Cup" for all possible years. His solution (that doesn't work) use the same URL for every ear which is wrong. The reason is because in the database all seasons of each tournament has it's own ID. This ID is used to create the URL. If you want data for different season you must know the right ID. I was trying to be helpful and extracted the ID's for 'FA Cup" for the possible years and created a map in order to get the data. Why do you think that my answer is not correct?

Comment: @v stoykov. hi, thanks for replying. this seems to be working now, thanks a lot. could you briefly tell me what the '%s' in the URL does, what the "'isAggregate': 'false'" does in the params and what '% year_tournament_map[year]' does in response please?

Comment: About the `%s` and `% year_tournament_map[year]` you can see at https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations. If you prefer to use `format` method you can change the code to use `{}` instead of `%s` and `url.format(year_tournament_map[year])` instead of `url % year_tournament_map[year]`.
About the `'isAggregate': 'false'` - this was in the original code and I'm not sure if it is required. You can see what response will be returned form the server if this is not in the parameters.